# How to use both reactive and non reactive MongoDB template on Webflux Application

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate, webflux

Currently, I'm developing a springboot webflux app for my project, where I use reactive-mongo-template and other reactive implementations. Now I have a legacy spring boot application that is implemented by WebMvc ( here i dont use the real springboot app. just using the core services implemented with mongoDB configurations) and it's using (normal) mongo-template for its implemented services. In my webflux app I'm trying to use the old services defined in the legacy application.

For that i tried importing the legacy app using component scan (`com.a.b.cservice.core.configuration`) and got some error. The problem is it wont detect the application correctly and the non-reactive mongo template.

Does the spring support only 1 mongo connection? These are the error logs i got;

```
[main] WARN  o.s.b.w.r.c.AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext - [] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mapperDAOSpringConfigurations': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mongoTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource 
    [com/a/b/cservice/core/configuration/MongoConfigurations.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.getDescription()Ljava/lang/String; 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.createCluster(DefaultClusterFactory.java:182)

The following method did not exist:

    com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.getDescription()Ljava/lang/String;

The method's class, com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/abc/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/4.0.5/mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar!/com/mongodb/connection/ClusterSettings.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/abc/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.12.7/mongo-java-driver-3.12.7.jar!/com/mongodb/connection/ClusterSettings.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings: file:/C:/Users/abc/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/4.0.5/mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings
```

Are there any workaround to work the legacy app with the webflux application with mongoDb? Or do i need to keep it as a seperate micro-service and call the relevent endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a few works and searches, I found the issue is not related to Webflux. purely a mongo client collision between legacy application and webflux drivers. so I exclude the drivers from legacy and imported the `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` along with the reactive `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive` version. (both are using the same version 2.3.5.RELEASE).

ps: found the same issue on here [Spring boot 2.0.5.RELEASE and mongo 4.0 connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722760/spring-boot-2-0-5-release-and-mongo-4-0-connection-issues/52827058#52827058)

Comment: Hi @namila007 , can you please tell me how did you manage to use both non-reactive and reactive repos? I have a similar need and I'm struggling to figure out the right config ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72731742/spring-mongodb-use-nonreactive-and-reactive-repository-at-once]here my SO question). Thank you!