# Spring + MongoDB Use nonReactive and Reactive repository at once

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, event-listener, changestream

I have a SpringBoot + Mongo application, implemented with non-reactive Repositories (*extends MongoRepository<MyDocument, String>*) and everything works fine.
Now I need to implement an auditing system and I wanted to develop it by using Mongo's **ChangeStreams** and Spring's Reactive Change Streams ([reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#reference)). I tried to create 3 classes to achieve this:

**MongoMessageListener**

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MongoMessageListener implements MessageListener<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>, MyDocument> {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>, MyDocument> message) {

        OperationType operationType = message.getRaw().getOperationType();

        log.info("Operation type is : {}", operationType);

        log.info("Received Message in collection: {},message raw: {}, message body:{}",
                message.getProperties().getCollectionName(), message.getRaw(), message.getBody());
    }
}
```

**MongoListenerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class MongoStreamListenerConfig extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    MessageListenerContainer changeStreamListenerContainer(
            MongoTemplate template,
            MongoMessageListener consentAuditListener,
            ErrorHandler errorHandler) {

        MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer =
                new MongoStreamListenerContainer(template, errorHandler);

        ChangeStreamRequest<ParentContentDocument> request =
                ChangeStreamRequest.builder(consentAuditListener)
                        .collection("my_document_collection")
                        .filter(newAggregation(match(where("operationType").is("update"))))
                        .fullDocumentLookup(FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP)
                        .build();

        messageListenerContainer.register(request, MyDocument.class, errorHandler);
        log.info("> Mongo Stream Listener is registered");
        return messageListenerContainer;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "myDatabase";
    }

    @Bean
    ErrorHandler getLoggingErrorHandler() {
        return new ErrorHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleError(Throwable throwable) {
                log.error("Error in creating audit records {}", throwable.getMessage());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**MongoStreamListenerContainer**

```
public class MongoStreamListenerContainer extends DefaultMessageListenerContainer {

    public MongoStreamListenerContainer(MongoTemplate template, ErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        super(template, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15), errorHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAutoStartup() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I also added a repo which extends `ReactiveMongoRepository<MyDocument, String>`

When I try to run my application it raises multiples errors of ClassNotFoundException ([...] `'reactiveStreamsMongoClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/internal/connection/InternalConnectionPoolSettings`) , or @Autowired to import repositories into Services not satisfied (*Autowired(required=true)}*)

In my Main.java class I tried to set both `@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.my.path.to.repository")`  and `@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories("com.my.path.to.reactive.repository")` , but nothing seems to work.
I doubted I could't squeeze together non-reactive and reactive repos, but I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68435903/how-to-use-both-reactive-and-non-reactive-mongodb-template-on-webflux-applicatio) and some more, so I guess you can.
I tried to follow [this Spring project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/tree/main/src/main/asciidoc/reference) step-by-step, but I always get ClassNotFound errors.

In my pom I have

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
 <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
 <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
 <artifactId>mongodb-driver-reactivestreams</artifactId>
 <version>4.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
 <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
 <version>3.4.19</version>
</dependency>
```

I really cant' see what I'm missing: if it's just some configurations or if I can't mix non-reactive and reactive repos (even though I found users say you can). Any help will be VERY much appreciated, it's driving me a bit crazy! Thank you so much!

Comment: its seems like you are missing some libraries, in my project I'm using `com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient` and `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate` as `primaryBean`s and for non reactive `com.mongodb.client.MongoClient` and `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate` , here i exclude `exclude = { MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class }` from my @sprinbootApplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you asked in one of my old [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68435903/how-to-use-both-reactive-and-non-reactive-mongodb-template-on-webflux-applicatio/68465666?noredirect=1#comment128484604_68465666), I will share what I did on my **webflux** project. I'm using an old library written in web MVC in my project where the non-reactive mongo is used.
I'm using the following dependencies;

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

my reactive mongo config looks like this. here I'm using the mongo URI connection string to connect, you can also use user/pass for this

```
@Configuration
public class ReactiveMongoConfiguration extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {

  private final NioEventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();


  @Override
  @Bean
  @Primary
  public MongoClient reactiveMongoClient() {
    ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(MY_DB_URI_KEY);
    return MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings.builder().applyConnectionString(connectionString)
        .streamFactoryFactory(NettyStreamFactoryFactory.builder().eventLoopGroup(eventLoopGroup).build()).build());
  }

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public ReactiveMongoTemplate reactiveMongoTemplate() {
    return new ReactiveMongoTemplate(reactiveMongoClient(), getDatabaseName());
  }

  @Override
  protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return new ConnectionString(MY_DB_URI_KEY).getDatabase();
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void shutDownEventLoopGroup() {
    eventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully();
  }
}}
```

My old web MVC library contains non-reactive mongo bean that looks like this,

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfigurations {

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
            ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(MY_DB_URI);
            MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(connectionString);
            mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, connectionString.getDatabase());
            return mongoTemplate;
    }
}
```

on my main application I excluded following auto configurations;

```
exclude = { MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class }
```

now you can use both reactive an non-reactive mono templates by injecting. :)

Comment: Thank you @namila007 ! I followed the set up and now I can use both the repositories :) it was all in the libraries/config as you suggested. Many thanks!

Comment: Hi again @namila007 :) Hope to find you well! I'm facing some issue with the reactive repos because they open too many connections, without closing them. Did you have the same problem as well?

Comment: @Barbi use mongo pool connection. you can enable pool connection by mongo uri. check the docs

Comment: sure, but wouldn't it just fix a maximum only to the single pool's size, and not to how many pools created?

Comment: @Barbi im not sure what's u r asking, `https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/connection-pool-overview/` check this. set a max,min pool size and a maxIdle time. so this will only apply to your java connection where you use this URI.